# How can I disassemble a function in a file without going into python interactive interpreter

Tags: python

So I have the following script, test.py:

```
def foo(x):
    y=x*2
    return y

print foo(10)
```

I run this command to disassemble it: `python -m dis test.py`. The problem is, it does not show the byte code of function foo.

Can you show me how I can make a simple BASH or Python script so that, given a Python script name and a function name, I can run it at command line to list the bytecode of the function?

[**UPDATE**]
OK, here it is:

```
dis_py_f() {
  python -c "import dis; import $1; dis.dis($1.$2)"
}
```

Thanks [Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist) for the tip.

Comment: `python -c 'import test; print(test.foo.__code__)'`? Not sure about the exact name of `__code__` though.

Comment: That's going to *run* the script, or at least any parts of the script not inside an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard.